# Celery - how to use multiple queues?

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I want to create a multiple queues for different tasks. For example `emailqueue` to sending emails or `pipedrive` queue to sync tasks with `pipedrive API` so `email` does not have to wait until all `pipedrives` are synced and vice versa.

I'm new in routing and I tried two approaches to create queues but none of them seemes to work.

1. This is a preferred approach. I tried to define queue inside `@task` decorator

   ```
   @task(bind=True,  queue='pipedrivequeue')
   ```

   def backsync_lead(self,lead_id):
2. settings.py

   ```
   CELERY_ROUTES = { # tried CELERY_TASK_ROUTES too
       'pipedrive.tasks.*': {'queue': 'pipedrivequeue'},
      ...
   }
   ```

In both cases, when I run `celery worker` manually, I see only one default `celery` queue.

```
(project) milano@milano-PC:~/PycharmProjects/project$ celery -A project.celery worker -l info

 -------------- celery@milano-PC v4.2.2 (windowlicker)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.15.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic 2019-04-12 17:17:05
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         project:0x7f3b47f66cf8
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379//
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost/
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 12 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery


[tasks]
  . project.apps.apis.pipedrive.tasks.backsync_all_stages
  . project.apps.apis.pipedrive.tasks.backsync_lead
```

As you can see in this line:

```
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

There is probably just one queue. I want to use this queue only for tasks without queue specified.

Do you know where is the problem?

**EDIT**

```
   (project) milano@milano-PC:~/PycharmProjects/peoject$ celery inspect active_queues
Error: No nodes replied within time constraint.
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to run a worker with the queue named explicitly, then django will be able to feed into that queue;

```
celery worker -A project.celery -l info  # Default queue worker
celery worker -A project.celery -l info -Q pipedrivequeue  # pipedrivequeue worker
celery worker -A project.celery -l info -Q testqueue  # testqueue worker
```

Comment: Can't I just run one worker (concurrency is in my case 12)? I know that I can specify multiple queues in one worker.

Comment: its only partially correct, celery by default will work on all configured queues. his issue is that he doesn't have queues defined in settings (CELERY_QUEUES @Milano)

Comment: @marxin Ok fair point, that's different to how I have things configured to put jobs into separate queues.

Comment: @marxin setting `CELERY_QUEUES = (
    Queue('celery'),
    Queue('testqueue'),
)` seems to have no effect. The output is still the same.

Comment: apparently it has been renamed to CELERY_TASK_QUEUES in more recent versions


btw, you can run multiple queues using commas, -Q a,b,c

Comment: @markwalker_ and its correct as well, just wanted to note that its not necessary to run it with explicitly named queue